# How to enable dataGridView inline editing ?

Tags: c#

I have a dataGridView I want to enable inline editing, I can make that by setting the value of ReadOnly to false but the editing is temporary when I close the form and re-open it the changes are missed

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Grid datasource has an ability to update its underlying data. In case of SqlDataSource there should be Insert/Update/Delete commands specified, for LinqDataSource there should be AllowUpdate/AllowInsert/AllowDelete. Keep in mind that LinqDS based on `select new ()` but not the entity (Table) is always read only.
2. Make sure grid row loses its focus. Default edit logic of DataGridView works only once row focus has been changed. You could also implement your own triggers, however it'll require a tiny bit more efforts.